# SQL group command nested too deeply; without join or subquery

Tags: sql, group-by

I have an `ORDERS` table with columns

```
ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE
```

I want to display the order month and number of orders for the month when the maximum number of orders were placed

Expected output is

| MONTH | TOTAL_ORDERS |
| --- | --- |
| Dec 20 | 17 |

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY') MONTH, COUNT(ORDER_ID) TOTAL
FROM 
    ORDERS
GROUP BY 
    TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY')
HAVING 
    MAX(COUNT(ORDER_ID))
```

I get this error:

> Group function nested too deeply in line 4

So I tried:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY') MONTH, COUNT(ORDER_ID) TOTAL
FROM 
    ORDERS
GROUP BY 
    TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY')
HAVING 
    COUNT(ORDER_ID) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(ORDER_ID))
                       FROM ORDERS 
                       GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY'));
```

which is also not passing for multiple databases.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above queries are product specific.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `RANK()` here on top of your current `GROUP BY` query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY') MONTH, COUNT(ORDER_ID) TOTAL,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(ORDER_ID) DESC) rnk
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'Mon-YY')
)

SELECT MONTH, TOTAL
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

The problem with `HAVING MAX(COUNT(ORDER_ID))` is that you are trying to find the largest count across the query.  But this itself requires another subquery, hence the error message.